# Run native Nodejs in AS400 / iSeries

Tags: node.js, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to run Node.js on AS/400 server in order to use Node.js toolkit for IBM i.

I have installed Node v6.14.4 and NPM 3.10.10 and I'm following this documentation to test node.js: https://developer.ibm.com/articles/i-native-js-app-ibmi-with-nodejs/#access-ibm-i-native-objects

I created the sample javascript file and when I run (from PASE terminal), I get this error:

```
node /home/njs/sample.js

/sample.js:1                                                                
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿
½ï¿½ï¿½Kï¿½ï¿½ï¿½M È ï¿½ï¿½@ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ]^                               
 SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token                
     at createScript (vm.js:56:10)                       
     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)            
     at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)               
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10) 
     at Module.load (module.js:494:32)                   
     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)                 
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)          
     at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)                
     at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)                    
     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:160:9)
```

I supposed there is a problem with npm and I tried with a very simple js file (an only one console.log) and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue. It was because an enconding problem.

I was creating javascript files with EDTF on AS/400 environment and that was a problem. I created a new file with notepad and upload by Navigator for i and works properly.